# How to compare datetime between dataframes in multi logic statements?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I am having issue comparing dates between two dataframes from inside a multi logic statement.

df1:

```
 EmailAddress     DateTimeCreated
    1@1        2019-02-12 20:47:00
```

df2:

```
 EmailAddress     DateTimeCreated
  1@1.com         2019-02-07 20:47:00
  2@2.com         2018-11-13 20:47:00
  3@3.com         2018-11-04 20:47:00
```

I want to do three things, whenever there is a row in df1:

```
 1. Compare to see if `EmailAddress` from df1 is present in df2:
 1a. If `EmailAddress` is present, compare `DateTimeCreated` in df1 to `DateTimeCreated` in df2, 
 2. If `DateTimeCreated` in df1 is greater than today-90 days append df1 into df2.
```

In simpler words:

I want to see email address is present in df2 and if it is, compare datetimecreated in df2 to see if it has been greater than today-90days since last time person answered. If it has been greater than 90days then append the row from df1, into df2.

My logic is appending everything not sure what I am doing wrong like so:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

df2.append(df2.loc[df2.EmailAddress.isin(df1.EmailAddress)&(df2.DateTimeCreated.ge(datetime.today() - timedelta(90)))])
```

what am I doing wrong to mess up on the date?

EDIT:

In the above example, between the dataframes, the row from df1 would not be appended bc DateTimeCreated is between TODAY() - 90 days.

Comment: You are appending the filtered `df2` to itself which is confusing to me. How do you know that everything is being appended does is just double the size?

Comment: Good point, I open to pushing the row if it meets the conditions into another frame.

Comment: _Greater than 90 days_ meaning newer than T-90? It just feels more intuitive to me that you're looking for records that are older than T-90 and then update df2 from the newer record in df1

Comment: @kerwei you are correct greater than 90

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer inline comments for the explanation. Please note that you need to rename your df1 columns to match df2 columns in this solution.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

from datetime import timedelta, datetime

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'EmailAddress':['2@2.com'], 'DateTimeCreated':[datetime(2019,2,12,20,47,0)]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'EmailAddress':['1@1.com', '2@2.com', '3@3.com'], 
    'DateTimeCreated':[
        datetime(2019,2,7,20,47,0), 
        datetime(2018,11,13,20,47,0), 
        datetime(2019,11,4,20,47,0)]})

# Get all expired rows
df3 = df2.loc[datetime.now() - df2['DateTimeCreated'] > timedelta(days=90)]
# Update it with the timestamp from df1
df3 = df3.set_index('EmailAddress').join(df1.set_index('EmailAddress'), how='inner', rsuffix='_r')
df3.drop('DateTimeCreated', axis=1, inplace=True)
df3.columns = ['DateTimeCreated']
# Patch df2 with the latest timestamp
df2 = df3.combine_first(df2.set_index('EmailAddress')).reset_index()

# Patch again for rows in df1 that are not in df2
df1 = df1.loc[df1['EmailAddress'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x not in df2['EmailAddress'].tolist() else 0) == 1]
df2 = pd.concat([df2, df1])

>>>df2
  EmailAddress     DateTimeCreated
0      1@1.com 2019-02-07 20:47:00
1      2@2.com 2019-02-12 20:47:00
2      3@3.com 2019-11-04 20:47:00
```

Comment: Additionally, if you want to ensure that you only update df2 if datetime in df1 is newer than T-90, you can drop the unwanted rows from df1 first before proceeding with the steps above. ```df1.loc[datetime.now() - df1['DateTimeCreated'] < timedelta(days=90)]```

Comment: thank you for the response. Few things:

1. Why are we updating with timestamp from df1? 
2. When i run this line `df3.columns = ['DateTimeCreated']`, i get error `ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 9 elements, new values have 1 elements`, why are we doing this? 
3. The row I dont want appended is still appending. Want to keep it simple has this email address responded in the last 90 days from today.

Comment: @RustyShackleford Okay, I've seen your updated question. Criterion 1a would be redundant is it not? 1. Check that email in df1 is in df2. 2. If it is, and if the DatetimeCreated is older than 90 days, append to df2. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I think you are correct on the 1a criteria, if email is not present, go ahead append into df2.

Comment: @RustyShackleford Sorry I'm a bit lost right now. Does that mean you append rows from df1 to df2 regardless of whether they exist in df2, so long as the DateTimeCreated is older than 90 days?

Comment: I want to append from df1 if email is not present, and if it is present, I want to check to see if the date is in the last 90 days

Comment: @RustyShackleford And if the DateTimeCreated in df1 is within the last 90 days you'll update df2?

Comment: no just df2. All we want to do is compare the date in df2

Comment: @RustyShackleford You need a boolean output then? A new column to indicate whether the DateTimeCreated in df1 is within the last 90 days of the DateTimeCreated in df2

Comment: @RustyShackleford I just updated my answer to fix the final part of the answer to patch for rows that do not exist in df2. Can you see if this is what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Try
1.  left join df1 and df2 which meeting the condition 1 email address same
    combined_df = df1.join(df2,how="left",lsuffix="df1_",rsuffix="df2_")
2.  calculated the gap between df1 datetimecreated and today
    gap = pd.datetime.today()- combined_df.DateTimeCreated_df1

3. return the index which gap >90
   mask = combined_df.gap>90
4. df2.append(df1[mask])

Note:I think you may need the combined_df only, the 4th step append should lead to duplicated or confused data. Anyway, you can choic use step 1,2,3,4 or only used step 1,2,3